# Python doc issues

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python.  I'm coming from C++ and Ruby and basically, I'm struggling to understand the doc.

[This](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) Ruby doc lists all the methods and operators and gives an example and an explanation.

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) C++ doc (though not official) does a similar thing.

My question is, where is this for python?  I'm looking [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) at the moment; my issue, however, is that I cannot see where the examples are (is there an example of the use of, say, the `append` method -- I know it's a pretty easy and obvious method to use; however, I'm sure that there are methods which are not so obvious).  Furthermore, I don't understand where the operators are documented.  For example, the `+` operator when used with string appends a character, and when used with a list, appends an element.  Where is this documented?  Is there no doc similar to the Ruby or C++ one?

Thanks.

Comment: How hard did you look? Just a few lines under where `list.append` appears in the page you link to is the text: `An example that uses most of the list methods:`, followed by the code examples. What's missing?

Comment: I cannot dream why you're having this problem.  Google "python documentation", first result is [this page](http://www.python.org/doc/), which has a link _right on it_ ["Browse Current Documentation"](http://docs.python.org/2/).

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked to shows examples of `append` as well as other list methods.  That is the tutorial, and is not meant to be a complete, concise listing of all information.  If you want the reference manual that lists methods and such all in one place, look at [the library reference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/).  Methods and operators for `str` and other sequence types, for instance, are documented [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).